# Issues with CSS Clip-path positioning

Tags: css, svg, css-position, clip-path

I'm having difficulties setting SVGs positions with clip-path property. In fact, I have 2 SVG files, star.svg and wave.svg.

What I'm trying to achieve is to position the star relatively to its html parent, and, in an independant manner, position the wave  such as only the part of the wave which overlaps the star is visible.

The objective is to animate the wave by translating and scaling it freely without affecting the star position (which will stay at its initial position), in a way that it will only be the part of the wave which overlaps the star which will be visible.

I tried it by integrating the wave.svg inline to my html and adding it the "clip-path" CSS property with a value of "url(star.svg)" but this way I can't manage to position both the star and the wave independently.

I would be so grateful of your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet? Maybe easier for you to use mask-image instead

Comment: Without any code we can't help you.